# jQueryUI and Bootstrap buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using: bootstrap.min, jquery-1.10.2, jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.
Using these libs I want to provide drag'n'drop feature. Bootstrap buttons should be draggable, but they aren't. Console log is clear. jQuery & jQuery UI are loaded & works.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btn.verticalButton').draggable({
            connectToSortable: '.container',
            containment: 'document',
            helper: function(){ return $(html); }
        });
        $("#droppable").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this);
                $(ui.draggable).remove();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Html:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
         <div class="panel panel-info text-center">
            <div class="panel-heading  text-center">Buttons</div>
            <div class="btn-group-vertical">
               <button class="btn verticalButton">B1</button>
               <button class="btn verticalButton">B2</button>
               <button class="btn verticalButton">B3</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "drug'n'drop"?  Is that kind of like slipping your HTML a roofie?  ;-)

Comment: lol.  had to comment on this...love it!!!  "drug'n'drop"

Comment: It is so hard to move on after a long break. :]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Default, jQuery UI will not add draggable to elements of type `button`.

According to the [API for the `Cancel` Option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel):

> Prevents dragging from starting on specified elements.
>   **Default**:`"input,textarea,button,select,option"`

If you'd like to be able to use Draggable on buttons, you have to override the cancel option by specifying `cancel: false`

```js
$('.btn.verticalButton').draggable({cancel:false});
```

## [Working Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/8g62E/)

Or you can try changing your `button` element to an `a`nchor element:

```html
<a class="btn btn-default">B1</a>
```

#### [Anchor Test Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/8g62E/5/)

Also, the `helper` option function you're using seems to be interfering with the drag operation.
In order to use [`connectToSortable`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-connectToSortable), you should use `helper: "clone"`.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to drag a `button`, you can throw it into a `div` and add the `{cancel:false}` option to the `draggable` function. For example:

```
<div class="verticalButton"><button class="btn">B1</button></div>
```

and then

```
$('.verticalButton').draggable({cancel:false});
```

[Here the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpatz/ByUmV/1/)